# Typoscript operators - Value of filelink referencing to another one

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I've set up the Typoscript below, but the last line doesn't work.
I want `20.filelink` to have the same content as `10.filelink` *(the real code is more complex and that bit is redundant)*.

```
lib.test = COA
lib.test {

  10 = TEXT
  10.value = A value

  10.filelink {
    path = fileadmin/path/
    target = blank
    stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>
    }

  20 = TEXT
  20.if.isFalse.data = subheader
  20.value = Another value
  20.filelink =< lib.test.10.filelink

}
```

Copying *(with the `<` operator)* works, but not `=<` as stated.

I've also tried without the `lib.test.` or with just `=` but without any success.

- **Is what I want to do possible?**
- **What did I not understand about operators?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did not understand. Apparently, **you can only copy or reference *Content Objects***.

The answer then is to reference the entire object, and to modify and add what needs changing. In this case it would be:

```
lib.test = COA
lib.test {

  10 = TEXT
  10.value = A value

  10.filelink {
    path = fileadmin/path/
    target = blank
    stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>
    }

  20 = < lib.test.10
  20.if.isFalse.data = subheader
  20.value = Another value

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put it out of the curly brackets  :

```
lib.test = COA
lib.test {

  10 = TEXT
  10.value = A value

  10.filelink {
    path = fileadmin/path/
    target = blank
    stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>
    }

  20 = TEXT
  20.if.isFalse.data = subheader
  20.value = Another value
}
lib.test.10.filelink =< lib.test.20.filelink
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work… And I think it should then be `lib.test.20.filelink =< lib.test.10.filelink` shouldn't it?